# 16.04 satellite c55-c5268

Tags: drivers, uefi

I have been trying mightily to fix my wifi on this pc with a full Ubuntu 16.04 installation - no windows partitions; straight ubuntu.  I have tried many of the suggestions including drivers bcmwl-kernel-source for braodcom.  I am not sure this particular issue has been addressed. I am about to switch to another operating system, as I cannot deal without wifi.
I have been advised after a brain injury to try to get back to work in the IT world. Please exercise some patience with me instead of saying that this question has been answered.
I understand there may be issues with the UEFI on a pure Ubuntu installation. I have tried all recommended installs, etc.that I can find.
I know you don't appreciate repeat questions, but please give me a break on this one. If anyone knows a fix without giving me a hard time, I would appreciate it. We are all human here. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) so yes, the question has been fully answered already and this is the complete guide for everything Broadcom. If you have a specific issue after following the guide please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure what my issue was, I tried all the steps and received some error messages.  As I am a newbie, I took the easy way out and bought a Panda Wireless USB adapter for $13.  It took 1 minute to set up.  Model PAU05